# Symfony custom many-to-many with checkbox

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Having **Session**, **Person**, **Participant**, I'm trying to create a **Session**, and a list with all **Persons** to check the **participants**.

The `PersonInSession` table keeps `participants_id`s and the `session_id`.

I'm getting the following Error:

> Unable to transform value for property path "person": Expected a Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection object.

I want to create a Session and directly check the participants in the same form.

**PersonEntityType**

```
class PersonEntityType extends AbstractType
{    
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name');
    }
}
```

**SessionEntityType**

```
class SessionEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('description')
            ->add('participant', CollectionType::class, 
                array(
                   'entry_type' => ParticipantEntityType::class,
                   'by_reference' => false,
                   'allow_add'    => true,
                   'allow_delete' => true,
                )
            );
    }
}
```

**ParticipantEntityType**

```
class ParticipantEntityType extends AbstractType
{   
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('person', EntityType::class,
                array(
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:PersonEntity',
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'expanded' =>'true',
                    'multiple' => 'true'
                )
            );
    }
}
```

**PersonEntity**

```
class PersonEntity
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ParticipantEntity", mappedBy="person")
     */
    private $participant;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->participant = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**SessionEntity**

```
class SessionEntity
{
    private $id;
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ParticipantEntity", mappedBy="session")
     */
    private $participant;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->participant = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**ParticipantEntity**

```
class ParticipantEntity
{
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PersonEntity", inversedBy="participant")
     */
    private $person;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SessionEntity", inversedBy="participant")
    */
    private $session;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->person = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, show code of **PersonEntity**

Comment: You should show the code of `SessionEntity` and `ParticipantEntity` too

Answer (score 0):

You should have:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection

class ParticipantEntity
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var PersonEntity[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    private $person;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->person = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
```

Otherwise it cannot work as is.

Answer (score 0):

in `SessionEntityType`, the `participant` field (you would better rename it to `participants` as that would be more meaningful) is a `CollectionType` field. So in its `entry_type` (`ParticipantEntityType`) you need to add a field which maps to a **Collection** property of the target Entity (`ParticipantEntity`).

In that entity you have `person` which has wrongly a `ManyToOne` relationship with your `participant`. So It should be defined as:

**ParticipantEntity**

```
class ParticipantEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonEntity")
     */
    private $persons;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->person = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

I strongly recommend you to revise your entities, as they are clearly the source of problem.